# What do = and == etc. mean when specifying conda and pip package version numbers in YAML files

Tags: pip, conda

We use YAML files to specify our conda and pip environments. In them we can specify which version numbers we need using, for example, any one of these lines

```yaml
- cudatoolkit=10.2.89
- cudatoolkit=10.2.*
- cudatoolkit==10.2.89
- cudatoolkit==10.2.*
```

I am having trouble finding the documentation for what `==` vs. `=` means in these package requirements and what other restrictions could be written and how.

What is the difference in this setting between `=` and `==`? Do these meanings differ between conda and pip? Where is the correct documentation (Google & Bing are not great at searching for symbols like those)?

Comment: While search engines generally do not do well when searching for these symbols, you can always go to a page where you think some piece of the puzzle might be, use the find in page function, and then look for a reference/manual on the topic. That will usually yield at the very least better search terms and often times the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) but it didn't help. The link to the [conda package match specifications](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html#package-match-specifications) you gave in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63452615/575530) is the starting point I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-matching), pip's version specification operators include only `==` which means to match the exact version specified. [Conda's package matching specifications](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/package-spec.html) include `==` which is the same as PEP 440's `==` for exact version specification and their own operator, `=`, which is for fuzzy package matching.