# I'm learing about Conda environment.yml and I'm not sure how to get Conda to find a certain version of dependancy

Tags: python, django, conda, wagtail

So I want to be able to build a environment  that contains all libs I need for my project that im going to port to Docker.

So far my yml looks like this:

```
name: wt
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.*
  - django=3.1.1
  - wagtail=2.11
```

So judging by the [compatibility link](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/upgrading.html#compatible-django-python-versions) I have the correct versions to run Wagtail but when I goto call `conda env create -f environment.yml` I get:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - wagtail=2.11
```

So I had a look on the Conda repo and I can't see a version 2.11. How would I get V 2.11 when can only get with v1 or v 2.7 which are both incompatible?

I have checked Wagtail Github and they are on version 2.7 but version 2.1 has LTS and thats why I would like to use it.

Comment: Don't you need a comparison operator (`==`) when specifying package version rather than assignment (`=`) as you have?

Comment: @pavel In Pip you need double == but going off the documentation you only need one = https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=environment.yml#create-env-file-manually

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't used yml files for environment setup. If for some reason yaml doesn't work why don't you exclude wagtail from your environment file and then try to install version 2.1 into the environment using either conda or pip?

Comment: Becuase I think I've just fixed it!

Comment: Oh, then congrats!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay the documentation for creating a conda env is a bit spotty so I will do a clone & push later to fix that. So below is an example file of what I've discovered you can do with 'environment.yml'.

```
name: environment-name
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7.*
  - django=3.1.1
  - pip
  - pip:
    - wagtail==2.11.*
```

**name:**

Reference name of the environment.

**channels:**

These are the repositories on the CondaCloud that Conda searches when installing, [example here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=django&sort=_name&sort_order=1&reverse=true). Please note that 'channel' means the package owners username.

**dependancies:**

The package you want to install may or may NOT include version numbers. if you want to declair a version number after a second/third/fouth decimal but not X decimal you may use a wildcard '*' to specify any. You also can include Pip but make sure you include it as a Conda dependancy first. It also worth mentioning that Conda uses  a single '=' and Pip uses two '==' when specifying a version number.

Comment: Some tips: `anaconda` channel is a subset of `defaults`, so you don't need both. Typically, if you are going to need `conda-forge` it should be prioritized over `defaults`/`anaconda`. You don't need the `.*` to spec Python 3.7; just `python=3.7` is more idiomatic. Not sure why you include patch version in `django` spec. One would only need that if you plan to use `conda (install|update)` commands later and want to keep that specific version locked in. Generally, if starting from YAML, then subsequent changes to the env should be mediated through editing the YAML then recreating.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I agree that the documentation is spotty, but in practice I think Conda uses `==` for exact versions and `=` for "fuzzy matches" (appends a `.*`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63452234/what-do-and-etc-mean-when-specifying-conda-and-pip-package-version-numbers and also https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/main/conda/models/match_spec.py#L99